# Return z-value of distribution - python

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation, distribution, gaussian

I have a bivariate distribution that is generated from the xy points for each `Group` in `'Int_1','Int_2'`. I normalise the distribution through the `Norm` and pass that to the contour to display the z-value.

I'd like to return the z-value of the bivariate distribution at the xy point displayed in `'Item_X','Item_Y'`. An example of this is located in the figure below using the white scatter point.

Eventually, I'll pass the z-value of `'Item_X','Item_Y'` at each point in time to a data frame and append it back to the original df.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal as mvn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import RectBivariateSpline

df = pd.DataFrame({'Int_1': [1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 2.0], 
           'Int_2': [1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0],
           'Item_X': [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
           'Item_Y': [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],               
           'Period': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
           'Group': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B'],
           'Item': ['Y', 'Y', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B'],
           'id': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '1', '2', '3', '4']})

Group_A = [df[df['Group'] == 'A'][['Int_1','Int_2']].to_numpy()]
Group_B = [df[df['Group'] == 'B'][['Int_1','Int_2']].to_numpy()]
Item = [df[['Item_X','Item_Y']].to_numpy()]

period = df['Period'].drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop = True)

def bivart_func(member_no, location, time_index, group):

  if group == 'A':
    data = Group_A.copy()

  elif group == 'B':
    data = Group_B.copy()

  else:

    return

  if np.all(np.isfinite(data[member_no][[time_index,time_index + 1],:])) & np.all(np.isfinite(Item[0][time_index,:])):

    sxy = (data[member_no][time_index + 1,:] - data[member_no][time_index,:]) / (period[time_index + 1] - period[time_index])

    mu = data[member_no][time_index,:] + sxy * 0.5

    out = mvn.pdf(location,mu) / mvn.pdf(data[member_no][time_index,:],mu)

  else:
    out = np.zeros(location.shape[0])

  return out

xx,yy = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-10,10,200),np.linspace(-10,10,200))
Z_GA = np.zeros(40000)
Z_GB = np.zeros(40000)

for k in range(1):
  Z_GA += bivart_func(k,np.c_[xx.flatten(),yy.flatten()],0,'A')
  Z_GB += bivart_func(k,np.c_[xx.flatten(),yy.flatten()],0,'B')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,8))
ax.set_xlim(-10,10)
ax.set_ylim(-10,10)

Z_GA = Z_GA.reshape((200,200))
Z_GB = Z_GB.reshape((200,200))

Norm = xx,yy, (Z_GA - Z_GB)

cfs = ax.contourf(*Norm, cmap = 'magma')

ax.scatter(Item[0][1,0],Item[0][1,1], color = 'white', edgecolor = 'black')

f = RectBivariateSpline(xx[0, :], yy[:, 0], Norm)
z = f(df['Item_X'], df['Item_Y'], grid = False) 
print(z)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The Z-score is a parameter that allows you to compare different normal distributions. Any normal distribution depends on the Z-score in the same way.

Z-score is defined by

[image: Z-score]

And the probability density function is
[image: Normal distribution]

For any distribution if you replace `z` in the definition of `f(x)` you always get `exp(-0.5*z**2)/(sigma * sqrt(2*pi)` .

In your case you have a ratio of probability, you can find an analogous to the z-value of it but it will have a different interpretation. In order to do this I will try to cast a ratio of normal PDFs to a scaled normal PDF with different means and covariances.

#### Ratios of PDFs as a scaled PDF

This would be more appropriate in a forum with latex enabled, I will write the equations in a python-like syntax

A multivariate distribution could be described as

`a * exp(-(x - mu).T @ A @ (x-mu))`

If you have the ratio of two distributions you can express as
`(a1/a2) * exp(-(x - mu2).T @ A1 @ (x-mu2)) / exp(-(x - mu1).T @ A2 @ (x-mu2))`

Since ratio of exponentials is the exponential of the difference

`exp(-(x - mu2).T @ A1 @ (x-mu2) + (x - mu1).T @ A2 @ (x-mu2))`

Rearranging the terms
`exp(-x.T @ (A1 - A2) @ x + 2 * x.T @ (A1 @ mu1 - A2 @ mu2) + mu1.T @ A1 @ mu2 + mu2.T @ A2 @ mu2)`

The term `2 * x.T @ (A1 @ mu1 - A2 @ mu2)` combines the two linear terms, and will define where is the mean of the distribution, the terms  `mu1.T @ A1 @ mu2 + mu2.T @ A2 @ mu2` are constant, and will appear as a constant factor on the distribution.

```
exp(-(x - mu).T @ A @ (x-mu))
```

The center of the scaled gaussian is such that

`(A1 - A2)@ mu3 = (A1 @ mu1 - A2 @ mu2)`

Thus `mu3 = (A1 - A2).inv() @ (A1 @ mu1 - A2 @ mu2)` and `A3=A1-A2`

If `A3` is positive definite (all eigenvalues are positive), then the distribution will be a scaled gaussian with average `mu3`

```
a3 * exp(-(x - mu3).T @ A3 @ (x-mu3))
```

```
def combine(C1, C2, mu1, mu2):
  """
    Given two multivariate normal distribution in a n-dimensional space
    C1: Covariance of the first distribution
    C2: Covariance of the second distribution
    mu1: Center of the first distribution
    mu2: Center of the second distribution
  """

  A1 = C1.inv()
  A2 = C2.inv()
  C3 = (A1 - A2).inv()
  mu3 = C3 @ (A1 @ mu1 - A2 @ mu2)
  return C3, mu3
```

#### Multivariate z-value analogous

The z value is simply the square root of twice the negative argument of the exponential thus, given the the above equation you have (In terms of C, the covariance matrix)

```py
def zValue(C, mu, x):
  """
    C:  n x n covariance matrix
    mu: n x 1 center vector
    x:  n x 1 location vector
  """
  return sqrt((x-mu).T @ C.inv() @ (x-mu))
```

The zValue, will be a function of the ratio between the value at the curve "center" and the given point. It may be negative if the `A1 - A2`  is not definite positive, meaning that the function evaluated at the given point `x` is greater than the function evaluated at the point `mu3`.

Comment: Is it possible to generate a multivariate normal distribution from the `bivart_func`, from which a z-value can be derived? Does the question need to be changed to that?

Comment: I wrote the algebraic part of the solution in details, with the hope it will be useful. But the result is not a z-value in the sense of the gaussian z-value.

Comment: It is helpful in that I probably need to overhaul the entire code. Rather than retrofit it implementing your equations. Thanks